# Registry entry is deleted after reboot

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I save directory path to registry with this code:

```
HKEY hKey;
RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\BArtWell\\MyApp", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
RegSetValueEx(hKey,L"Directory",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)sz,(DWORD)wcslen(sz)*sizeof(wchar_t));
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

And it is working fine before reboot. But after reboot path HKCU\Software\BArtWell\MyApp doesn't exists. Tested on XP and Windows7 with same result. What I do wrong?

Comment: Run the app with admin rights?

Comment: Could it be a 64/32-bit redirection issue?

Comment: @BaliC: Run as usually. Program can use registry with admin rights?

Comment: @DanPuzey: program compiled as 32-bit. Windows 7 PC is 64-bit. XP PC is 32-bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`REG_OPTION_VOLATILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then replace it with 0.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried my program with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and i had this problem. Thanks